# FFmpeg conversion error: At least one output file must be specified

Tags: ffmpeg

Installed FFmpeg and it shows version and all correctly.

But even info FFmpeg command itself shows

```
FFmpeg -i Alice_In_Wonderland.mp4
```

Gives message like:

> ```
> FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c)  
> 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.    
> configuration: --prefix=/usr  
> --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --extra-cflags=-fPIC --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab   libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0   libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0   libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0   libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0   libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1   libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0   built on Nov  6 2009 19:11:04, gcc: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
>   
> Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate:  
> 49.93 (9986/200) -> 49.92 (599/12) Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2,
> from 'Alice_In_Wonderland.mp4':  
> Duration: 00:01:39.65, start:
> 0.000000, bitrate: 542 kb/s
>     Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
>     Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x270, 49.92 tbr, 24.96 tbn, 49.93 tbc
> At least one output file must be specified
> ```

Please tell me what's the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like the error message says, you need to give it an output file. The basic syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i Alice_In_Wonderland.mp4 Alice_In_Wonderland.avi
```

You can (and probably should) add options such as in this:

```
ffmpeg -i Alice_In_Wonderland.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag divx -vb 5000k -aspect 2.424 -r 23.976 -acodec ac3 -ac 6 -ab 384k Alice_In_Wonderland.avi
```

That will create a DIVX format file.

Comment: thanks for your reply @gorilla. Actually it expects three more packages, i tried with some packaes installations , nothing worked. OS reinstalled everything and its working now. Thanks